# MySQL python incorrect string value 1366 error

Tags: python, mysql

Im trying to run a python script that will reload a randomized table of names and codes but i keep getting the following error:

> _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xEB' for column 'selfFirstName' at row 1")

Which corresponds to this block of code:

```
for student in studentlist:
    print student.getData()
    student.target = studentlist[
        x + 1] if x < len(studentlist) - 1 else studentlist[0]
    cursor.execute(add_data, [
        student.first,
        student.last,
        student.grade,
        student.email,
        student.code,
        student.target.code,
        0,
        0
    ])
    cnx.commit()
    x = x + 1
```

I've searched around and I edited my.cnf to match utf8 formatting but i keep getting this error. is there any easy way around it?

Comment: What is the table schema?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE if not exists gotchaTable(id int(11) PRIMARY KEY "
                   "AUTO_INCREMENT, selfFirstName TEXT NOT NULL, selfLastName TEXT NOT NULL, "
                   "selfGrade TEXT NOT NULL, selfEmail TEXT NOT NULL, selfCode TEXT NOT NULL, targetCode TEXT NOT "
                   "NULL, targetsCaught TEXT, timeCaught DATETIME, isCaught BOOLEAN NOT NULL);`

Comment: That schema is missing charset information.

Comment: what do you propose?

Comment: the collation is utf8_general_ci

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams do you have any ideas?